# Create histogram of raster in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I want to create a value distribution chart, like a histogram or graph, of a raster image using:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
DEM <- raster("NR.tif")
hist(DEM)
plot(DEM)
```

`plot()` is used to validate my data and shows me an all green image. Supposedly band 1 of 3.
However I can't see other bands?
Obviously the distribution in the histogram doesn't represent interpolated values in the imagefile. 
A histogram created in ARCgis is here[hist](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcazm1pd84r8tf9/Vertical%20Nitrategradient%20Histogram.jpg?dl=0), which I believe represent the true values.

Any suggestions on how to create a histogram of the real values like the [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t279m5ojners7fl/NR.tif?dl=0).

Best, 
Mathias

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want to get: is levelplot {rasterVis}  (http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/) of any help?

Comment: not sure, if I understand correctly but: try `hist(DEM)` or `plot(density(DEM))`

Comment: I hope the edit clarified the issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/t279m5ojners7fl/NR.tif?dl=1", 
              tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif"), mode="wb")
library(raster)
library(tiff)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
DEM <- readTIFF(tf)
plot(as.raster(DEM))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(melt(DEM), 
       aes(value, fill=as.factor(Var3))) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge")
```

[image]

---

Or, with regards to your update

```
r <- as.raster(DEM)
tab <- as.data.frame(sort(table(r)))
ggplot(subset(tab, !r %in% c("#F0F0F0", "#000000")), 
              aes(x=r, y=Freq, fill=I(r))) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is defintely an improvement. But the histogram has counted the grey background thus not representing the calculated values. (Which is nitrategradient in a vertical watercolumn.) A histogram created with ARCmap has a significantly different distribution (https://www.dropbox.com/s/fcazm1pd84r8tf9/Vertical%20Nitrategradient%20Histogram.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: Yes, this is a classic RGB histogram, which you find in every image processing tool. Imho did the question not ask for geo spatial analysis. But you should be able to get where you want from thereon (e.g. you can exclude the one grey bg color.)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to be specific, guess I gotta try harder. Thanks for great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the NAvalue to the background color and then call the hist() function or use the ggplot commands from lukeA:

```
library(raster)
ras <- stack("Downloads/NR.tif")
NAvalue(ras) <- 240
hist(ras)
```

This results in the following plots:
[image]

Comment: Also see: `plotRGB(ras)`